# UserControl parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am creating a windows universal application. I have a listbox with an itemsource of objects of a class I defined myself. Within the itemtemplate for the listbox I have a UserControl. This UserControl contains a couple of buttons, that contain images. When the button is clicked the image should change and a setting should be changed. For the changing of the setting I need the object that is binded to the itemtemplate, that the usercontrol is part of.

How do I get the the specific item that is the source of this instance of the UserControl?

I have read this:
[Windows Phone 8 usercontrol imagebutton with different images for different states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032401/windows-phone-8-usercontrol-imagebutton-with-different-images-for-different-stat)

But that does not explain how to get objects of self defined classes. Only properties for ui elements.

Edit: Since I am not allowed to show you the actual code (contract related business), I made you some sample code.

Click event in the usercontrol:

```
private void Important_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CustomClass customObject = ((sender as Button).DataContext as CustomClass);

        if (customObject != null)
        {
            Print.Debug("customObject : " + customObject .ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Print.Debug("customObject is null");
        }
        Print.Debug("Important_Click: " + e);
        var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
        if (isImportant)
        {
            Important.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(resourceLoader.GetString("Important/Source")));
            isImportant = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Important.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(resourceLoader.GetString("Important_enabled")));
            isImportant = true;
        }
        hasDoneWork = true;
    }
```

Xaml that calls the usercontrol:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBlockWithSource" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Path=Source_Text}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" />

        <home:OptionButtons Name="ChatOptionsButton" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Source}" > <!-- trying to bind the object, not a variable within the object -->
        </home:OptionButtons  >
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Edit 2: forgot to explain the code.

In the above code snippets OptionButtons is the UserControl. The DataTemplate is the ItemTemplate of a ListBox that has its ItemSource property bound to a collection of CustomClass objects. The Important_Click event is the click event of a button in the OptionButtons UserControl that changes the source of an image.

Comment: The data item object should be accessible by the UserControl's `DataContext` property (unless you've otherwise assigned it in your DataTemplate).

Comment: How would one do that, exactly? I'm pretty new to this. :P

Comment: `var item = this.DataContext as YourItemClass;`, then check if `item` is not null.

Comment: The item is always null when I do this. I also tried to print the DataContext.ToString(). This gave a nullpointer, so I'm thinking the DataContext is always null. Maybe I'm doing it wrong in the xaml? I'm doing this:  
<AAA:BBB Name="XXX" Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Path=Reference_Id_Of_Object}" >
I'd prefer to get the object itself and not it's reference id, but I had no success when using the object name itself either. Any suggestions?

Comment: So `OptionButtons` is the UserControl in question and the DataTemplate is the ItemTemplate of a ListBox that has its ItemsSource property bound to a collection of `CustomClass` objects? We could guess all this, but it would be helpful if you'd explain the things you're showing here.

Comment: You are correct. I edited the post to include that explanation, I should've put it in there from the start, but I forgot.

Comment: It should work if you simply remove the DataContext binding from the OptionsButton in XAML. The default (inherited) DataContext in an ItemTemplate contains the respective item from the ListBox's Items collection.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. If you make an actual answer containing the things you've told me I will accept it as the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default inherited `DataContext` of the elements in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl already references the particular item from the `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection of the ItemsControl. Therefore it is not necessary to set it explicitly.

Remove the `DataContext` binding from your XAML:

```
<home:OptionButtons Name="ChatOptionsButton" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: Do you by chance know how to get the DataContext at an earlier stage? Now it's always in the click event, but what if for example I would want it in the constructor or in a Loaded event? I've tried it the same way as with the click events, but now it always gives a nullpointer.

Comment: There is a DataContextChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Handle the Click event for the button in UserControl

In that you can get the item bind in that user control.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var item = ((sender as Button).DataContext) as yourCustomClass;
   if(item != null)
      \\ do your stuff .. 
}
```

Comment: Yeah... my item is always null. I suspect it has to do with the XAML that references the UserControl. I edited my question to include a code sample.